# Is there any way to split the string to rows in R?

Tags: r

I have following string "[Time].[Fiscal Year].&[2014]}^[Time].[Fiscal Half Year]^[Time].[Fiscal Quarter]^[Time].[Month]" and need to split the string in below format. Kindly help me to find the way to fulfill my requirement.

[image: Column values must be as per image]

Comment: Please share a reproducible example using `dput`.

Comment: Thank you Ronak, i hope you are looking for below code.                             
Test <- "[Time].[Fiscal Year].&[2014]}^[Time].[Fiscal Half Year]^[Time].[Fiscal Quarter]^[Time].[Month]"
dput(Test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` to split on `^` and `gsub` to find the pattern `[*].[*]` and put the result in a `data.frame`.

```
data.frame("Time Value"=
 gsub("(\\[.*?\\]\\.\\[.*?\\]).*", "\\1", strsplit(x,"\\^")[[1]])
 , check.names = FALSE)
#                 Time Value
#1      [Time].[Fiscal Year]
#2 [Time].[Fiscal Half Year]
#3   [Time].[Fiscal Quarter]
#4            [Time].[Month]
```

Data:

```
x <- "[Time].[Fiscal Year].&[2014]}^[Time].[Fiscal Half Year]^[Time].[Fiscal Quarter]^[Time].[Month]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code can make what your want. Given string `s` as below

```
s <- "[Time].[Fiscal Year].&[2014]}^[Time].[Fiscal Half Year]^[Time].[Fiscal Quarter]^[Time].[Month]"
```

then the data frame can be formed via

```
r <- unlist(strsplit(s,"\\^"))
df <- data.frame("Time Value" = unlist(regmatches(r,gregexpr("\\[.*?\\]\\.\\[.*?\\]",r))),check.names = F)
```

such that

```
> df
                 Time Value
1      [Time].[Fiscal Year]
2 [Time].[Fiscal Half Year]
3   [Time].[Fiscal Quarter]
4            [Time].[Month]
```

Comment: @Kop You are welcome! I updated my answer such that it looks the same as the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Simple Base R solution:

```
gsub( "\\.\\&.*", "", unlist(strsplit(x, "\\^")))
```

Data:

```
x <- "[Time].[Fiscal Year].&[2014]}^[Time].[Fiscal Half Year]^[Time].[Fiscal Quarter]^[Time].[Month]"
```